# Disable pidfile for celerybeat

Tags: celery, celerybeat

`celeryd` doesn't require a pidfile, but `celerybeat` seems to. Is there any way to disable it? I'm using Upstart to manage processes so using a pidfile is redundant.

Comment: Have you had any luck disabling the pid file?

Comment: No, even using `celeryd -B` causes a pid file to be created. I basically gave up and just specified a path to work around permissions constraints on my system.

Comment: Ah okay. I've got a similar situation, it's not running as root so it can't save in /var/run or equivalent. I've found this seems to work though: `python manage.py celerybeat --schedule=/var/my_app/celerybeat-schedule --pidfile=`. I'm running it through Django, not sure if that has an effect. Having an `=` and then nothing after it appears to stop one being created. Let me know if it helps. Will submit it as an answer if so!

Comment: @michael that works a treat (am also using django-celery).

Comment: @bradley.ayers I've added my comment (which seems to work) as an answer — would be great if you could accept!

Comment: @Rich Great, glad it works for you. Feel free to up-vote the answer I just posted :-)

Comment: This question is relevant to Docker users as well.

Comment: This question is relevant for Heroku users as well, since we're not supposed to write anything on the filesystem, because dynos often restart, always with an empty filesystem.

Answer (score 80):

The following seems to have worked for a few people so I'm submitting it as the answer:

```
python manage.py celerybeat --pidfile= --schedule=/var/my_app/celerybeat-schedule
```

`--pidfile=` (an empty string as the pidfile arg) seems to stop one being created.

Comment: Very great tip for avoid CeleryBeat to create PID file before see he must create a another in Django conf

Comment: Wanted to mention that I just tried this on supervisor and it works like a charm :)

Comment: Perfect solution!

Comment: works for me! great for using celery inside Docker.

Answer (score 3):

So for me, I ammended the following in my development `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
web
    ...
    command: bash -c "python3 manage.py makemigrations && python3 manage.py migrate --run-syncdb && python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8982"
```

to:

```
web
    ...
    command: bash -c "rm -rf celerybeat.pid && python3 manage.py makemigrations && python3 manage.py migrate --run-syncdb && python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8982"
```

I'm sure there is a more elegant way of cleaning up this file on startup or even shutdown?

Answer (score 3):

Deleting celerybeat.pid from base directory helped me fixed this issue
[image]

Comment: This worked for me for docker-compose environment.