# Restart: always with force-recreate

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In `.yml` file I have defined: `restart: always`. Is it possible to create this restart as the equivalent of `--force-recreate` flag?

I have an issue with `XVFB` and standard restart doesn't solve an issue but restarts with the flag `--force-recreate` help and I'm looking for an opportunity to do it automatically.

Comment: Related to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53523649/docker-compose-restart-policy-dont-preserve-changes-in-image), where the recommendation was to use swarm

Answer (score 1):

Always restart the container if it stops. If it is manually stopped, it is restarted only when Docker daemon restarts or the container itself is manually restarted. (See the second bullet listed in restart policy details) Source [Link](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/):

No --force-recreate is not the equivalent to restart: always

"--force-recreate Recreate containers even if their configuration and image haven't changed."

I use a Makefile for start/stop is also more practical.

Example:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

# Docker: up
up:
    docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build

# Docker: down
down:
    docker-compose down


... and so on
```

And than i can use like "make up, make down, make logs, make attach ..."

By the way, in most projects I also use for Automatic Restart and better logging [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/)

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. The OP wants to somehow include `--force-recreate` in their Docker Compose `restart: always` policy